# Program to hold down click until button is pressed?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, minecraft

I am trying to set up a Minecraft fish farm, but it requires you to hold the right mouse button. Is there a program or some code that can start holding when a button is pressed and stop when it is pressed again?

Comment: a paperweight? :)

Comment: I currently do that, but it keeps slipping.